# How to reduce direct DOM manipulations in a JavaScript app using a virtual DOM, and how do I evaluate the optimizations?

Tags: jsx

How to optimize and minimize direct DOM manipulations in a JavaScript application, and what role could a virtual DOM strategy play in this process? Additionally, describe the methods you would use to assess the effectiveness of these optimization techniques.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  // Simulate fetching data from an API and updating the state
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.example.com/data')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(fetchedData => {
        // Update state with the fetched data
        setData(fetchedData);
      });
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect runs once on mount

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(item => (
        <div key={item.id}>{item.content}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```